# error al buscar por nombre programa c++

Tags: c++

que tal amigos estoy creando un programa en c++ con estructuras:
2.  Almacenar en un arreglo los nombres y las edades de 10 personas. Buscar el nombre correspondiente a una edad determinada y la edad correspondiente a una persona. Ambas opciones deben ser accesibles a través de un menú:
a) Buscar por nombre.
b) Buscar por edad.
c) Salir.

pero en el momento de realizar la consulta por nombre me dice que la persona de dicho nombre no existe en el registro dejo el código completo agradecería pronta ayuda

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h> //NUEVA LIBRERIA
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <D:\c++\proyecto final\libreria validacion de enteros\bibliotecavalidaint.cpp>
#define maximo 2
using namespace std;
using namespace validacionIngresoint;

struct per{
char codigo[25];
char nomb[50];
char nombre[50];
char direccion[50];
char sexo[30];
int edad;
}persona[maximo];
char inicio[1];


/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */

int main() {

char opc,resp,aux,entero;
string estudiante;
int contador, i, j,c,k,bandera,edadbuscar;
int p=0;


do{
    opc=aux;
    system ("cls");

    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), FOREGROUND_RED);
    printf("\tBien Venido Usuario\n");
    printf("Elige alguna de las siguientes Opciones\n");
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);
    printf("\n\ta) Ingresar 10 Personas\n");
    printf("\tb) Buscar por nombre \n");
    printf("\tc) Buscar por Edad \n");
    printf("\td) Salir\n");
    cout<<"--> ";cin>>opc;
    do{
    bandera=aux;
    opc=tolower(opc);
    if((opc!='a')&&(opc!='b')&&(opc!='c')&&(opc!='d'))
    {
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), FOREGROUND_GREEN);
    printf("\n---<Por favor elija una opcion valida>---: ");
    bandera=1;
    cin>>opc;
    }
    }while(bandera==1);

    switch(opc){

                case 'a':
                    {   

                        system("cls");
                        p=0;
                        for(contador=0;contador<maximo;contador++)
                        {
                            p=p+1;
                            cout << "\n Codigo de persona: "<<p;
                            cin.getline(persona[contador].codigo,25);
                            cout << "\nIngrese nombre: ";
                            cin.getline(persona[contador].nombre,50);
                            cout << "Ingrese direccion: ";
                            cin.getline(persona[contador].direccion,50);
                            cout << "Ingrese sexo: ";
                            cin.getline(persona[contador].sexo,30);
                            cout << "Ingrese edad: ";

                            do{
                                persona[contador].edad=tomarInt();
                                if(persona[contador].edad<1||persona[contador].edad>100)
                                {
                                 cout << "\nEdad Ingresada no valida: \n";
                                }                       
                            }while (persona[contador].edad<1||persona[contador].edad>100);
                            }
                         cout<<"Usted ingreso "<<p<<" de 10 alumnos: ";
                         system ("pause");

                            break;
                     }

                case 'b':
                 {
                        do{
                        cin.getline(inicio,1);
                        p=0;
                        system ("cls");
                        SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);
                        cout << "\n Ingrese nombre a buscar: ";

                        cin.getline(persona[1].nomb,50);
                        cout<<persona[1].nomb<<endl;
                        system("pause");
                        for(i=0; i<maximo; i++)
                        {
                            cout<<persona[i].nombre<<endl;
                            cout<<persona[1].nomb<<endl;
                               if (persona[1].nomb == persona[i].nombre)
                            {
                                p=p+1;
                                cout<<p<<endl;
                                cout << "SU CODIGO" << "----> " << persona[i].codigo << endl;
                                cout << "SU NOMBRE" << "----> " << persona[i].nombre << endl;
                                cout << "DIRECCION" << "----> " << persona[i].direccion << endl;
                                cout << "EDAD" << "----> " << persona[i].edad << endl;
                                cout <<"________________________________________________________________________\n";
                                putchar('\a');
                            }
                        }
                        if(p==0)
                        {
                            SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), FOREGROUND_RED);
                            cout<<"\n No existen alumnos "<<persona[1].nomb<<endl;
                            SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), FOREGROUND_GREEN);
                            cout<<"\n Si decea realizar otra busque digite s: ";
                            cin>>resp;
                        }
                        if(p>0)
                        {
                            cout<<"\n Si decea realizar otra busque digite s: ";
                            cin>>resp;

                           }

                }while(resp=='s'||resp=='S');
    break;
                }


                   case 'c':
                   {
                        do{
                        cin.getline(inicio,1);
                        system ("cls");
                        SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);
                        cout << "\n Ingrese edad a buscar: " << endl;

                        do
                        {
                        cin>>edadbuscar;

                        for(k=0; k<maximo; k++)
                        {
                            if (edadbuscar== persona[k].edad)
                            {
                                cout << "SU CODIGO" << "----> " << persona[k].codigo << endl;
                                cout << "SU NOMBRE" << "----> " << persona[k].nombre << endl;
                                cout << "DIRECCION" << "----> " << persona[k].direccion << endl;
                                cout << "EDAD" << "----> " << persona[k].edad << endl;
                                cout <<"________________________________________________________________________\n";
                                putchar('\a');
                            }
                        }
                        if(edadbuscar!=persona[k].edad)
                        {
                            SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), FOREGROUND_RED);
                            cout<<"\n No existen alumnos de "<<edadbuscar<<" años\e"<<endl;
                            SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), FOREGROUND_GREEN);
                            cout<<"\n Si decea realizar otra busque digite s: ";
                            cin>>resp;
                        }

                        }while((edadbuscar!=persona[k].edad)&&(resp=='s'||resp=='S'));

                            cout<<"\n Si decea realizar otra busque digite s: ";
                            cin>>resp;
                }while(resp=='s'||resp=='S');

                        break;
                   }

                   case 'd':{


                    break;
                   }

                   }

    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);             
    cout<<"\nDigite S para Realizar otra operacion segun opciones de menu: ";
    cin>>resp;
    }while(resp=='s'||resp=='S');
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score -1):

A la hora de comparar strings, como es tu caso a la hora de comparar los nombres, no es bueno usar `==`, es mejor usar un comparador de strings. Te sugiero cambiar la línea `if (persona[1].nomb == persona[i].nombre)` por lo siguiente: `int strcmp ( const char * str1, const char * str2 )`. Esta condición te devolverá un `0` cuando los dos strings sean iguales.

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo de como funciona ese comando:

```
char key[] = "apple";
  char buffer[80];
  do {
     printf ("Guess my favorite fruit? ");
     fflush (stdout);
     scanf ("%79s",buffer);
  } while (strcmp (key,buffer) != 0);
  cout<<"Correct!!"<<endl;
```

Digo que no es bueno usar `==` porque `==` no va a funcionar siempre, solo en los casos en los que el string sobrecargue el operador. En el caso en el que no sobrecargue el operador, al usar `==` estarás comparando la dirección de memoria en lugar del objeto en sí. Por ello yo prefiero usar `strcmp`.

Comment: `no es bueno usar ==, es mejor ... ` Entiendo de ahí que ¿ **si se puede usar `==` para comparar cadenas** ?

Comment: Con eso quiero decir que == no va a funcionar siempre, solo en los casos en los que el string sobrecargue el operador. En el caso en el que no sobrecargue el operador, al usar == estarás comparando la dirección de memoria en lugar del objeto en sí. Por ello yo prefiero usar strcmp.

Comment: Deberías de editar la respuesta y explicarlo ahí; la gente no suele leer los comentarios, y tal y como está creo que se presta a confusión.